# Call bean method on focus lost

Tags: jsf-2

How do I call a bean method on focus lost?

I tried this,

```
<h:inputText id="receipeCode" value="#{receipeBean.receipeCode}" 
    onfocuslost="#{receipeBean.view}" />
```

However, the method is not called when the cursor is moved to the next input field.

Comment: You can achive this with remoteCommand of primefaces or jsFunction of richfaces

Answer (score 4):

The "focus lost" event is called "blur" event. So, you *basically* need `onblur`:

```
<h:inputText ... onblur="#{receipeBean.view}">
```

**However**, this doesn't call the specified method on blur. This merely prints the `view` property as a `String` representing some JavaScript code during generating the HTML output. It's expecting a getter method something like this:

```
public String getView() {
    return "alert('peek-a-boo')";
}
```

If you have actually a `view()` method, you'll face a `PropertyNotFoundException` on this one. Also, this isn't exactly "calling a bean method on blur". This is more "generating JavaScript code which should run on blur".

In order to actually invoke a JSF backing bean method on blur, you need a `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{receipeBean.view}" />
</h:inputText>
```